# Mapping string list to pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

Just curios  better way to map pandas column against a list.

```
ref_list=['a','b','c','d']
lst = [0,2,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['no'])
```

expected output

```
   no map
0   0  a
1   2  c
2   1  b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

map with a enumerated dictionary:

```
df['map_'] = df['no'].map(dict(enumerate(ref_list)))
#df['map_'] = np.array(ref_list)[lst]
```

---

```
print(df)

   no map_
0   0    a
1   2    c
2   1    b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(lst, np.array(ref_list)[lst]), columns=["no", "map"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   no map
0   0   a
1   2   c
2   1   b
```